# How to select data using conditions from associations?

Tags: data, filtering, associations

Consider the following dataset:

```
data = Table[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]}, {i, 1, 10^3, 1}];
```

I would like to impose different conditions on it using associations:

```
condition := 
 Association[{"First" -> 1 < #[[1]] < 2, 
   "Second" -> ArcTan[#[[1]]] > 0.5, 
   "Third" -> Exp[-(#[[1]]^2/2)] < 0.05}]
selectedData[selection_] := Select[data, condition[selection] &]
```

However, something went wrong: while

```
Select[data,1 < #[[1]] < 2&][[1]]
```

works, the desired code fails:

```
selectedData["First"][[1]]
```

> Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.

It seems that the condition inside the association is not recognized as a normal condition:

```
condition["Second"]
```

> True

Could you please tell me how to fix `selectedData`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these modifications:

```
ClearAll[condition, selectedData]

condition = 
 Association[{
   "First" -> (1 < #[[1]] < 2 &), 
   "Second" -> (ArcTan[#[[1]]] > 0.5 &), 
   "Third" -> (Exp[-(#[[1]]^2/2)] < 0.05 &)
 }]

selectedData[selection_] := Select[data, condition[selection]]

selectedData["First"]

(* Out: {1.47076, 0.65529, 0.927465} *)
```

In short, associate *fully-constructed pure functions* to the labels, so the association query returns a whole working pure function that can be used inside `Select`.

As a note, the parentheses in the association are needed for precedence reasons.